# Error while creating Parquet table from CSV using Apache Drill

Tags: csv, parquet, apache-drill

I'm Trying to create a Parquet table from a CSV extract (generated from an Oracle database table) that has over a million rows. about 25 of those rows have null values for the START_DATE and CTAS is failing to interpret `""` as `null`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE dfs.tmp.FOO as
select cast(columns[0] as INT) as `PRODUCT_ID`,
cast(columns[1] as INT) as `LEG_ID`,
columns[2] as `LEG_TYPE`,
to_timestamp(columns[3], 'dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS a') as `START_DATE`
from dfs.`c:\work\prod\data\foo.csv`;



Error: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always include a `CASE` statement to filter out the empty entries:

```
CREATE TABLE dfs.tmp.FOO as
select cast(columns[0] as INT) as `PRODUCT_ID`,
cast(columns[1] as INT) as `LEG_ID`,
columns[2] as `LEG_TYPE`,
CASE WHEN columns[3] = '' THEN null
  ELSE to_timestamp(columns[3], 'dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS a') 
END as `START_DATE`
from dfs.`c:\work\prod\data\foo.csv`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NULLIF() function as below

```
CREATE TABLE dfs.tmp.FOO as
select cast(columns[0] as INT) as `PRODUCT_ID`,
cast(columns[1] as INT) as `LEG_ID`,
columns[2] as `LEG_TYPE`,
to_timestamp(NULLIF(columns[3],''), 'dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS a') as `START_DATE`
from dfs.`c:\work\prod\data\foo.csv`;
```

NULLIF will convert empty string to null and the casting won't fail.